# Finding a string in a string list with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I would like to find a string in a string list where exists in a collection.

E.g. in my collection "works"

```
tag: {"cute", "handsome", "modest"}
```

If I type "cute" from searching field. It will search to find "cute" tag in string list tag.

How can i do this with mongodb queries?

Comment: Can you provide valid JSON of your document?

Comment: This is invalid hash and invalid array. Do you really have document with such structure? I doubt it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YyN6JPzt this is model of the collection

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all works, which have "cute" tag, then use following query:

```
{ tag: "cute" }
```

MongoDb will understand that tag is array and check "cute" item existence. C# sample:

```
var works = db.GetCollection<WorkBase>("works");
var cuteWorks = works.Find(Query.EQ("tag", "cute"));
```

Or you can use LINQ (*MongoDB.Driver.Linq*)

```
 var cuteWorks = from w in works.AsQueryable()
                 where w.Tags.Contains("cute")
                 select w;
```

---

BTW don't forget to map your properties correctly. E.g. property `Tag` should have correct element name specified:

```
[BsonElement("tag")]
public List<string> Tag { get; set; }
```

Also consider to rename property to `Tags` because you have collection of tags, not single tag.

Comment: cute is just an example. If user types "handsome" I must find record have tag named handsome.

Comment: @user3008355 you do know how to use variables in c#?